# Not everything is about you

Tags: meaning, american-english, vocabulary, slang, north-american-english

What does it actually mean when people say "Not everything is about you."
when they use it?

Comment: It's a reproach to someone who appears to be self-centred.

Comment: It means that some of it is about me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone thinks that "everything is about them", it means they are being self-centered and egotistical. No matter what the subject is, the person finds a way to make themselves the focus. An example might be if a friend needs to attend a funeral for a loved one, and you get upset because they have to cancel plans you had together.

When someone says "not everything is about you", they are chiding someone for being self-centered.